# Understanding UIView.animate and how completion closures work

Tags: ios, swift, animation, closures, completion

Is there is a way to interrupt animations in a way that doesn't "cancel" (rewind) them, but rather "fast-forwards" them forcing their completion closures to run earlier than originally planned?

Background:

In IOS, one can "animate a view with duration" and include a completion closure as well... using UIView's static method animate() like this:

```
class func animate(withDuration: TimeInterval, animations: () -> Void, completion: ((Bool) -> Void)? = nil)
```

A real-life example might look like ***EXHIBIT-A*** here:

```
// assume we have a UILabel named 'bigLabel'

func animationWeNeedToDo() {

            UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: {
                self.bigLabel.alpha = 0
            }, completion: {
                if $0 {
                    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: {
                        self.bigLabel.center.x -= 20
                    }, completion: {
                        if $0 {
                            self.updateMainDisplay()
                        }
                    }) }
            })
        }
```

So we have a UILabel, *bigLabel*, that we are first animating to "fade," then we are chaining to yet another animation inside the completion of the first, then yet again in the completion of the second, we run the all-important function, updateMainDisplay().

But this simple example could be much more complex involving many more views.  It could be imperative that updateMainDisplay() executes. ;)

The updateMainDisplay() function is important because it "resets" all the views, returning the app to a neutral state similar to when the app is originally started... sort of "re-calibrates" everything.

Anyhoo, the trouble is, if the user does something like push the home button early enough or segue to a new activity (modally, like settings... and then come back) while the animation is taking place, it never completes... *and so updateMainDisplay() does not get executed!* ...and things get complicated and nasty.

So, how to handle this problem?

Seems like something needs to be done in "onPause()" (I know this isn't Android)... like making sure that the animation is cancelled AND that updateMainDisplay() is executed.

But in order to do that you would have to check for all kinds of boolean states in the "onPause()" method.  I would much prefer if there were a way to guarantee that the animation will complete.

So, once again, I'm thinking it would be pretty awesome if there were a way to *not cancel the animations*, but to "force immediate completion" of all animations.

This is pseudo-code... but is there a way to do something like this:

```
var myAnimation = (animation) { // EXHIBIT-A from above } 

myAnimation.execute()

// if needed:

myAnimation.forceCompletionNow()
```

Does anyone know if that's possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Why not add a call to `updateMainDisplay()` in `viewWillAppear`? That way, if the user moves away from the screen, the method will be called when the user returns. As for the Home button being pressed, you can set an observer `NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(updateMainDisplay), name: Notification.Name.UIApplicationWillEnterForeground, object: nil)`

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you are checking the first argument of the completion closure. That indicates whether the animation finishes or not. And you only run `updateMainDisplay()` if that is true.

So in fact, the completion handler *will* be called even if the animation is not finished. It is *you* that told it to do nothing if the animation does not finish.

To fix this, just remove the `if $0` statement.

Now Xcode will show a warning because you did not use the first argument of the closure. To silence this warning, just put `_ in` at the start of the closure:

```
{ _ in
    // some code
}
```

Another thing that you can try is [`CABasicAnimation`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/cabasicanimation) which does not *actually* change the view's properties. It animates the `CALayer`s. If you update the view again in some way, the view will have gone back to its original state before the animation. You seem to want to reset everything after the animation finishes so this might be suitable for you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Yes I'm sure it doesn't run... but only if you press it right away after the animation begins... tested it with trusty print-debugging.  This will take me a while to test your answer.

Comment: I'm an idiot.  I figured out that if I change that "if $0" in the completion to "if ($0 || !$0)" then the completion does always execute as you expected.  Such wierd code is unnecessary I'm sure, but I don't really understand closures... and involving "$0" was the only way I could get Xcode to stop complaining.  It has something to do with a boolean value representing whether or not the animation completed.  Anyway... I don't know what to do with this question now. :S